# Is f being injective equivalent to this statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

We have two sets $X,Y$ with $f:X \to Y$. Show that a) and b) are equivalent.

a) $f$ is injective;

b) $f(X\:\backslash\:N)=f(X)\:\backslash\:f(N)$ for all $N\subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Suppose $f$ is injective.

Let $N$ be a subset of $X$.

If $N = X$ it's trivial that $f(X\setminus X) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset =f(X)\setminus f(X)$.  So let $N \subsetneq X$ and so $X \setminus N$ is not empty.

If $x \in X\setminus N$, then if $f(x) \in f(N)$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $y \in N$.  But $f$ is injective so that would mean $x = y \in N$ which is a contradiction so $x \not \in f(N)$ and $x \in f(X) \setminus f(N)$ which is not empty and $f(X\setminus N) \subset f(X)\setminus f(N)$.

Likewise if $y \in f(X)\setminus f(N)$ then $x = f^{-1}(y)$ is unique (as $f$ is injective).  $x \not \in f(N)$ so $x \not \in N$ so $x \in X\setminus N$ so $f(x) \in f(X\setminus N)$ and $f(X)\setminus f(N) \subset f(X\setminus N)$

So $f(X)\setminus f(N) = f(X\setminus N)$

2) Suppose $f(X)\setminus f(N) = f(X\setminus N)$ for all $N\subset X$.

Let $x \ne y$.  Let $N = \{x\}$.  Then $y \in X\setminus N$.  So $f(y) \in f(X\setminus N) = f(X)\setminus f(N)$.  So $f(y) \not \in f(N)$. But obviously $x\in N$ and $f(x) \in f(n)$.  So $f(x) \ne f(y)$.  So $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is injective. Let $y\in f(X-N)$, then there exists $m \in X-N$ such that $y = f(m)$. If $y \in f(N)$, then $y=f(n)$ where $n\in N$. So $f(n) = f(m)$. By injectivity $n=m \in X-N$, which is impossible. So $y \in f(X) - f(N)$.

Now suppose that $f(X-N) \subset f(X)-f(N)$ for each $N \subset X$. Then for $x\neq y$, $y \in X-\{x\}$, so $f(y) \in f(X-\{x\}) \subset f(X)-f(\{x\})$, i.e. $f(y)\notin f(\{x\})$, so $f(y) \neq f(x)$. Then $f$ is injective.